403 Clients Error: Forbidden for url: https://something.org/anotherthing/more%20things%20andfile.pdf
I was scraping a website and I tried to open a URL to PDF file to extract text from the pages. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error message
403 Clients Error: Forbidden for url: https://something.org/anotherthing/more%20things%20andfile.pdf.
Any tips to fix this issue?
Thank you 
import requests
import pymupdf  # PyMuPDF
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import time

def download_pdf_with_retries(url, retries=20, delay=5):
    """Download a PDF file with retry logic."""
    attempt = 0
    while attempt < retries:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Check for HTTP errors
            return response.content
        except (requests.RequestException, Exception) as e:
            print(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} failed for URL {url}: {e}")
           attempt += 1
            time.sleep(delay)  # Wait before retrying
    raise Exception(f"Failed to download PDF after {retries} attempts for URL {url}")


def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_content):
    """Extract text from a PDF byte content."""
    pdf_file = BytesIO(pdf_content)
    pdf_document = fitz.open(stream=pdf_file, filetype="pdf")
    data = []
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text()
        data.append({"page": page_num + 1, "text": text})
    return data

def process_pdf_url(url):
    """Process a URL to extract text from a PDF."""
    try:
        pdf_content = download_pdf_with_retries(url)
        return extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_content)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing URL {url}: {e}")
        return []  # Return empty list on failure


Can you actually open the link directly (eg in your browser)? Perhaps the remote site doesn't allow certain user agents to prevent scraping

Yes. I was able to open the url directly and there was no issue.

Try out Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python

Yes, I tried that: response = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)  where HEADERS is a dictionary of key-value of headers.

That's not really what I meant. Try setting the user-agent header to look like a common browser. Also, can you open the URL directly in an incognito / private browsing window? Perhaps you're missing some credential cookies in your Python script

I will try that. Thank you!!
